# How can i get all words from a string array using a return statement

Tags: java, android

I want to return words from a `String` array one after the other.

```
public String CurrentString(int move) {
    int currentString = 0;
    EditText ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed);
    String[] strings = ed.getText().toString().split(" ");
    int newString = currentString   move;   
    if (newString >= strings.length) {
        // if the new position is past the end of the array, go back to the beginning           
        newString = 0;  
    } 
    if (newString < 0) {
        // if the new position is before the beginning, loop to the end      
        newString = strings.length - 1;    
    }    
    currentString = newString;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), strings[currentString],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return strings[currentString];  
}
```

The problem is that my above code doesn't return all texts. Please, help.

Comment: It is really hard to understand your question because the code is something else. please fix it! also there are some bugs in your code! **currentString  ;**??

Comment: Consider looking at StringTokenizer.

Comment: "doesn't return all texts"... Well, yeah, you are returning one element from an array

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have not done enough "homework" and are having problems with arrays,
 (that's why people are down-voting [this is not a site for beginners who not do put in the required "research effort", the site would be **inundated**]).
The current trend is to downvote AND/OR leave a sarcastic comment ;O)
Also your code contains errors that will not compile, so you have not even bothered to test it ! ;O(
Lucky for you you cannot get a negative reputation !
Seriously please do some research (google it !)
Here is some code that may help. Use split to process your string into a string array:

```
        String string = "I want a string array of all these words";//input string
//                       ^   ^  ^    ^     ^    ^  ^   ^    ^
//                       0   1  2    3     4    5  6   7    8 //index
        String[] array_of_words;//output array of words
        array_of_words = CurrentString(string);//execute method
        Log.i("testing", array_of_words[8]);//this would be "words" in this example

        //later you might want to process commas and full stops etc...

            public String[] CurrentString(String string) 
            {
                String[] array = string.split(" ");   //use space to split string into words 
                //With the advent of Java 5, we can make our for loops a little cleaner and easier to read    
                for ( String sarray : array ) //loop through String array
                {
                     Log.i("CurrentString", sarray );//print the words
                }
                     return array ;//return String array
            }
```